# Signing into a mailbox via php curl

Tags: php, email, curl, authentication

I have a code to log into a mailbox, but this doesnt work for me. Can you help me to repair it? What am I doing wrong? I made an example mailbox for you, so feel free to use it.

Login form is on [this page](https://login.szn.cz/).

```
    <?php

$ch = curl_init ();
$Url = "https://login.szn.cz/loginProcess";
$fields = array(
    'serviceId' => "email",
    'returnURL' => "https://email.seznam.cz/",
    'username' => "PavelDoskocil@post.cz",
    'password' => "nmkdSxX6",
    'domain' => "post.cz",
    'login' => "Přihlásit se",
    'coid' => ""
);


$fieldsTrim = http_build_query($fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsTrim);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://seznam.cz");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;


?>
```

Comment: why reinvent the wheel - could you not use the various `imap` functions built into php to access the mailbox? You can work with `imap`,`pop` and `nntp` - though not all functions work with pop ( php5.3.2 )

Comment: Cause i need to use u function in web application after login into mailbox

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookie jar for this. You can use a variable for cookie jar

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '-');
```

or a tmp file.

```
$cookie = "/var/tmp/xy.ck";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
```

To debug what is happening inside, you can trace using enabling verbose mode

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesnt work, can you help me to fix it? Please?

Comment: With this response `it doesn't work` I (or anyone else) can't help you anymore. Be informative with your response.

Comment: If u will try to run it, only white page returns back. I have allow redirections and verbose, but nothing happens.